# Blank Row insertion using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I'm trying to create the vba code which can be used to repeat set of rows n times. So far I found below code and it worked well.

```
Sub CopyData()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "D")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "D")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "D")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

How can I add blank row after repetition? Please suggest

Comment: Do you want to insert a blank row after every iteration, or do you want to insert a blank row only once at the end of the sub?